# Closed form of geometric series $\sum_{i=1}^n p^{i+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^n p^i = \frac{p-p^{n+1}}{1-p}$, but I am not sure how the i+1 factors into the closed form for $\sum_{i=1}^n p^{i+1}$, what is the closed form for the second sum?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n p^{i+1}=p \sum_{i=1}^n p^{i}$, But your formula is wrong. $\sum_{i=1}^n p^{i}=\frac{p-p^{n+1}}{1-p}$

Comment: Thank you I will update it, so the +1 doesn't change the closed form?

Comment: It changes... by muliplying it by $p$

Comment: so it is $\frac{p^2 - p^{n+2}}{1-p}$ ?

Comment: Yes, You're right.

Comment: thank you I will create an answer for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically answered your question yourself.

You know,
$\sum_{i=1}^n p^i = \frac{p \left(p^n-1\right)}{p-1}$

Now

$$\sum_{i=1}^n p^{i+1} = p \sum_{i=1}^n p^i$$

So you get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n p^{i+1} =  \frac{p^2 \left(p^n-1\right)}{p-1}$$

Comment: @hardmath fixed it